# Redshift casting decimal to decimal

Tags: sql, select, casting, decimal, amazon-redshift

Why does casting a decimal to decimal lose all decimals? For example,

```
SELECT 1.5::DECIMAL
```

Returns `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decimal number has a precision (the total number of significant digits in the whole number) and a scale (the number of decimal digits).

In Redshift, the default precision is `18`, *but* the default scale is `0`, and automatic rounding is applied when casting, as [explained in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html#r_Numeric_types201-decimal-or-numeric-type):

> *scale*
>
> The number of decimal digits in the fractional part of the value, to the right of the decimal point. [...] The default scale, if not specified, is 0.
>
> [...]
>
> If the scale of an input value that is loaded into a table is greater than the scale of the column, the value is rounded to the specified scale.

So you would need to specify a scale when casting, for example:

```
SELECT CAST(1.5 AS DECIMAL(10, 5))
```